# Как сверстать подобный элемент (стрелка над картинкой)?

Tags: css

Есть блок с картинками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Над первой картинкой есть элемент в виде закругленной стрелочки, фон у которого - продолжение картинки? Если бы не было теней у блока, то можно было бы вставить белое png-изображение с прозрачностью в месте закругленной стрелочки. Как можно сверстать такой элемент, как на изображении, в случае с тенью у блока?

Comment: 1) Выбирать похожий цвет. 2) Вставлять изображение чуть скрытое вверху (через `background-position`) и стрелкой отображать скрытое.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Можете написать подробнее?

Comment: Делаем белую "шапку" для каждой картинки. Для шапки прописываем тень. Для неактивных элементов шапка сплошная. Для активных - с прорезью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, нужна фигурная обрезка с тенью по форме этой обрезки.

```css
img {
  height:220px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 20px, 80px 20px, 100px 0, 120px 20px, 200px 20px, 200px 220px, 0 220px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 20px, 80px 20px, 100px 0, 120px 20px, 200px 20px, 200px 220px, 0 220px);
}
div {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px gray);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px gray);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/12/23/08/43/flowers-1105254_960_720.jpg"><div>
```

Возможности и ограничения по браузерам: [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Важно, что filter применён к родительскому блоку, иначе он как и box-shadow, border-radius и border применяется к картинке до обрезки. Закруглить углы мне не удалось. Нашёл [он-лайн сервис подбора параметров clip-path](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, дополнил ответ

Comment: получается, что IE вообще не поддерживает?

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, не проверял, давно на него не рассчитываю, ну будет вид по-хуже, необрезанные картинки и без тени. Дайте IE умереть спокойно.  Edge вроде поддерживает filter http://caniuse.com/#search=filter, с clip-part проблема пока остаётся.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще это может быть блок похожим цветом как у картинки. Вот, например, полукруг

```css
.round{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position: absolute; 
    clip: rect(0, 400px, 200px, 0);
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
```

Comment: Блоков много на странице, картинки будут добавляться через CMS. Поэтому ваш вариант не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Изначально не понял ваш вопрос.
Для этих целей не нужно городить фигурки из css и html. Вам нужно либо взять полупрозрачную png картинку, либо использовать шрифты, например http://fontawesome.io/icon/map-marker/

Answer (score 0):

Легко. Нужно нарезать 2 картинки. 1 будет сплошная белая уже с тенью, а вторая с нужной прорезью. А дальше пишем код:

```css
.img-container{
  position: relative;
}
.img-container:before{
  content: '';
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(../img.png); /*Тут прописываем картинку без прорези*/
}
.img-container:hover:before{
  background-image: url(../img1.png); /*Тут картинка с нужной прорезью*/
}
```

Например