# Как сверстать такой макет?

Tags: html, css

[image: макет]

Не могу разобрать как сверстать такой макет? Главная проблема это треугольники вверху и с боку, может кто верстал? Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544802/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9

Comment: @Cheg если и дубликат, то точно не этого. Уж больно сложные там решения.

Comment: @Влад для вас они, может, и сложные. А вот предложенный вами вариант не позволит добавить стрелке тень, как это требуется на скриншоте

Comment: В споре рождается истина! Всем спасибо! Предложенные решения, я думаю, помогут многим. Я как начинающий верстальщик, к таким вариантам не пришёл! Ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с тенью у "стрелок":

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.block:before,
.block:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.block:before {
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.block:after {
  z-index: 1;
}

.block-1,
.block-1:before,
.block-1:after {
  background: #fff;
}

.block-1:before,
.block-1:after {
  left: 30px;
  top: -2px;
}

.block-2,
.block-2:before,
.block-2:after {
  background: #333;
}

.block-2:before,
.block-2:after {
  right: -5px;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block-1"></div>
<div class="block block-2"></div>
```

Comment: Идеально подходит под поставленную задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно стрелочки рисуют через добавление блока со срезанными (за счет прозрачного border) углами

```css
        .block {
            background: #a0a0a0;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .block::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left: 20px; bottom: -20px; /* Положение стрелочки  */
            border: 10px solid transparent;
            border-top: 10px solid #a0a0a0; /* Направление стрелочки */
        }
```

```html
 <div class="block">
        Ваш блок с Username
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Размер **after и before** разумеется можно менять

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.box{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-right:none;
  margin:100px;
  position:relative;
  background:#fff;
}
.box:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#fff;
  border-left:0;
  border-bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  left:93%; top:10%;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  z-index:10;
}
.box:before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:0;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё подходит. Очень помогли. РЕСПЕКТ!